# Set State in useEffect and console.log multiple times

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, setstate, rerender

I'm getting datas from mongoDb via axios (fetchData('/content'))

Everything works fine, then I put the values in another array (for later convenience) and set the texts state with this.

Everything works like a charm, but my console.log, display twice (four if React Strict Mode is enabled)
If I don't do the forEach (inside or outside useEffect, that doesn't matter) the console.log appears only once (twice in strict mode)

If someone can explain to me why is that ?

Here is the code : (fetchData refers to another function)

```
const [texts, setTexts] = useState('')

    useEffect(() => {
        const getText = async () => {
            const datas = await fetchData("/content")
            const values = []
            datas.data.forEach(text => {
                values[text.name] = text.tex_fr || text.items
            });

            setTexts(values)
        }
        getText()
    }, [])

    console.log(texts)
```

I tried map instead of forEach and tried to achieve this in useEffect or outside useEffect and nothing changed.

I'm new to React. Maybe that is perfectly normal? (but strange)

Thank you for your help!

Comment: 2 renders sounds normal. There's the first render when the component mounts, and then once you have data you set state and render again.

Comment: Changing the state will cause the component function to run again. So: you do the initial render, run the effect (which sets a state value), and then render again (with the new state value).

Comment: the first time it displays `''` then the response? looks like normal react lifecycle

Comment: For the first time yes this is '' then the response. But every time I'm making any change in the code without reloading the page or setState again, the console log still display twice (and state has the exact same value)
I thought with the argument [], useEffect runs only when the component mounts

Answer (score 0):

React Strict Mode intentionally performs double-invocations of certain functions, like render methods and effects. This is done to help detect side effects and other potential issues and to address this issue and get a clearer understanding of the actual state values, you should log the state inside a useEffect with a dependency on the texts state:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(texts);
}, [texts]);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried doing this but since I'm setting the state inside useEffect, if I'm using this argument [texts], then I have an infinite loop of console.log

But maybe my problem isn't one. I'll try to console.log the state inside useEffect for better readability.